# ¿Como utilizar TAB o ENTER cuando utilizo raw_input? Python

Tags: python

Hola quisiera saber como poder utilizar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> y <kbd>Tab</kbd> al momento de decirle al usuario que ingrese algo con raw_input

Codigo:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

outfile = open('codehero.txt', 'w') # Indicamos el valor 'w'.
outfile.write(raw_input("Ingresa lo que deseas agregar : "))
outfile.close()
# Leemos el contenido para comprobar que ha sobreescrito el contenido.
infile = open('codehero.txt', 'r')
print("""

          Este archivo fue modificado y leido correctamente""")
print(infile.read())
# Cerramos el fichero.
infile.close()
```

Para que al momento de que este escribiendo se permita <kbd>ENTER</kbd> y <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas leyendo por allí encontre algunos ejemplos y pues jugando con ellos culmine con esta función:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def leer(mensaje):
    print(mensaje)
    entrada = ""
    while True:
        caracter = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if caracter == '\t':
            break
        entrada += caracter
    return entrada
```

como puede observar lo que se hace es leer de la entrada caracter por caracter en busca de una tabulación y cuando se encuentra con el caracter de tabulación retorna la concatenación de estos.

> cabe destacar la ejecución queda de igual manera en espera hasta que
>   el usuario presione enter, pero solo si se encuentra una tabulación
>   saldra del loop.

tu código solo hay que cambiar el raw_input por el método leer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

def leer(mensaje):
    print(mensaje)
    entrada = ""
    while True:
        caracter = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if caracter == '\t':
            break
        entrada += caracter
    return entrada

outfile = open('codehero.txt', 'w') # Indicamos el valor 'w'.
outfile.write(leer("Ingresa lo que deseas agregar : "))
outfile.close()
# Leemos el contenido para comprobar que ha sobreescrito el contenido.
infile = open('codehero.txt', 'r')
print("\n\tEste archivo fue modificado y leido correctamente")
print(infile.read())
# Cerramos el fichero.
infile.close()
```

De todos modos aquí están links útiles:

- [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)
- [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465089/python-sys-stdin-read1-in-a-whiletrue-loop-consistently-executes-1-time-gett) ingles
- [quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-does-sys-stdin-work-in-Python) ingles

Comment: ¿Como podria introducir eso en lo que estoy haciendo?

Comment: solo podrías utilizar el método **leer** en vez de **raw_input** en tu código. leer retorna un string con toda la entrada. hasta que presionen tab y luego enter.

Comment: ¿Pero a lo que me refiero si, tu me dices que use leer en vez de raw_input  pero como el usuario ingresaria lo que quiere?

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres con cambiar el metodo leer pero la funcion no esta definida y si le pongo leer=raw_input sigue sin funcionar ENTER